# Compromised Ropes in Retail Stores

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, ropes, rope-management

Reposting this from a Facebook discussion. It's a picture taken from a retail store where they have attached a pin-tag through the rope to prevent theft; a common practice at this location.

My gut reaction is to avoid it like the plague, but I have a tendency to treat the rope like it's sacred. Has anyone seen this elsewhere? Would you climb on it?

[image: Rope in the Store]

Comment: Core is strands so it is not as bad as it looks but I would look to purchase rope elsewhere.  There has to be a better way to secure rope from theft.

Comment: Shouldn't do any damage to the rope, unless there was a barb on the end of that pin.  If it was me I'd make a stink to see if I could get the rope for cheaper, but in principle I'd probably shop elsewhere.

Comment: "Sorry, I don't want the display item - could you get me one still in its packaging, please?"

Comment: If they put it through the end few inches of the rope, you wouldn't care.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ewww. I'm guessing they punch pin tags through $700 gore tex jackets as well? And condoms? Even if the amount of damage is minimal, it's still something I would rather not do to my rope. Some climbers do use a needle and thread/dental floss to make small whippings on the rope to indicate that the rope ends are approaching. However, there is a large difference between carefully easing a sharp needle through the rope and a retail worker, chugging along at minimum wage, shoving one of those generally ragged and burred pins through the rope.

As you mention, the amount of damage is probably not severe. Similarly, storing the ropes in a vat of motor oil or sewage would probably still be safe. This doesn't mean that any of those are best practices and speaks more to the great extent that manufactures go through to make sure their products are safe. Furthermore, I don't recall the UIAA having a rope testing category for standard falls with a security tag through the rope.

At the very least it shows a lack of respect for the end user (my making money is more important than your safety). There are so many other ways to prevent shoplifting a rope. For example:

- Even moderately alert retail staff. Ever have someone walk by at the crag and stuff your rope into their pocket without you noticing? Neither have I. It isn't exactly an object that lends itself easily to shoplifting.
- Using a cable-type security device through the center of the coil, such as [one of these](https://americantheftprevention.com/Cable-Wraps-amp-Keepers/Cable-Locks-c20/). While it would be possible to uncoil the entire rope and free the rope from the cable, it is mighty hard to imagine that someone wouldn't notice.
- Using adhesive magnetic sensor tags on the packaging/hidden away inside the coils of the rope.
- Keeping ropes inside a locked cabinet/display case or behind a counter.

If the establishment is unwilling to alter their practices, I would strongly urge you to contact the manufacturers of the ropes. Having worked specialty outdoor retail, this would be the sort of thing that a reputable manufacturer would drop a dealer for.

Comment: At the very least they could tag it at the end of the rope; the part that's not going to be anything but the tail end of a knot when the rope's being used.

Comment: @ShemSeger at the very least they could not do this and stop trying to kill their customers

Comment: I wonder if the store will figure out the issue, remove or move the tags and leave the ropes on the shelf, to sell to buyers who will be unaware of the abuse?

Comment: @erfink I highly doubt the integrity of the rope is compromised, a pin would pass right through the core without damaging it as long as it didn't have sharp barb on it or something. It just looks bad being skewered.

Comment: @ShemSeger The best we can say is "probably." Keep in mind that the security pins *are* in fact commonly barbed and have ridges in order to increase the bite. Even clothes often have noticeable damage. "Probably safe" is one thing if I'm building a rap anchor in the alpine, but something very different if I'm buying a brand new rope. There are a *huge* amount of liability disclaimers built into outdoor retail---consider that Yvon sold off Chounaird Equipment under advice of counsel, in order to protect Patagonia from incoming litigation about a customer putting a harness on incorrectly.

Comment: @erfink Shoplifting tags don't have barbs, they have a ridge that the other side of the tag catches. Comparing it to putting a hole in a condom or Gore-Tex jacket is just silly and hyperbolic. There is published data on what a hole in either would do. You won't find that for a nylon rope. In this case, the manufacturer can't drop the retailer - that's a Simond rope in a Decathlon store, it would be like REI dropping REI.

Comment: @oasisbob Cool. Find me data from EN or UIAA showing that a rope drop tests to full strength after being skewered with a security tag. Until then, I consider it reckless endangerment. And if it's a store brand, that makes it all the easier to sack the store management and responsible employees.